# how to call vxworks API reboot in code

Tags: vxworks

I need to reboot the vxworks machine after some random time.
I am calling reboot api in vxworks as below:

```
extern "C" void reboot_vxWorks()
{
    reboot();
}
```

its not working.
Can anyone please suggest how to call the reboot api in code

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If not, please add more information

Answer (score 1):

Have look on this link ...

http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/rebootLib.html

You need pass some specific argument to that routine

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear from your question in what way it is not working, but in anycase the code is not quite correct. The reboot function has this signature:

```
void reboot(int starttype);
```

where starttype indicates if you want a normal boot, no autoboot, to clear memory, or a quick boot.

You should have included `<rebootLib.h>`, which would allow the compiler to generated a warning / error here (dependant on compiler settings).

If your issue however is that it reboots, but not in the way you wanted, selecting the appropriate start type here may well fix that issue as well.